# scipy.odeint returning incorrect values for second order non-linear differential equation

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, differential-equations

I have been trying to solve the second order non-linear differential equation for Newton's Law of Universal Gravitation (inverse square law):

`x(t)'' = -GM/(x**2)`

for the motion of a satellite approaching the earth (in this case a point-mass) in one dimension

[image: MS Paint skills]

using numpy.odeint with a series of first order differential equations, but the operation has been yielding incorrect results when compared to Mathematica or to simplified forms of the law (∆x = (1/2)at^2).

This is the code for the program:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def deriv(x, t):            #derivative function, where x[0] is x, x[1] is x' or v, and x2 = x'' or a
    x2 = -mu/(x[0]**2)
    return x[1], x2

init = 6371000, 0          #initial values for x and x'

a_t = np.linspace(0, 20, 100)   #time scale

mu = 398600000000000      #gravitational constant

x, _ = odeint(deriv, init, a_t).T

sol = np.column_stack([a_t, x])
```

which yields an array with coupled a_t and x position values as the satellite approaches the earth from an initial distance of 6371000 m (the average radius of the earth). One would expect, for instance, that the object would take approximately 10 seconds to fall 1000 m at the surface from 6371000m to 6370000m (because the solution to 1000 = 1/2(9.8)(t^2) is almost exactly 10), and the mathematica solution to the differential equation puts the value at slightly above 10s as well.

[image: The mathematica solution]

Yet that value according the odeint solution and the sol array is nearly 14.4.

```
  t                    x
  [  1.41414141e+01,   6.37001801e+06],
  [  1.43434343e+01,   6.36998975e+06],
```

[image: pylab figure]

Is there significant error in the odeint solution, or is there a major problem in my function/odeint usage? Thanks!

Comment: Everything looks basically correct.  I would try and see what you get with a smaller time step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (because the solution to 1000 = 1/2(9.8)(t^2) is almost exactly 10),

This is the right sanity check, but something's off with your arithmetic.  Using this approximation, we get a `t` of

```
>>> (1000 / (1/2 * 9.8))**0.5
14.285714285714285
```

as opposed to a t of ~10, which would give us only a distance of

```
>>> 1/2 * 9.8 * 10**2
490.00000000000006
```

This expectation of ~14.29 is very close to the result you observe:

```
>>> sol[abs((sol[:,1] - sol[0,1]) - -1000).argmin()]
array([  1.42705427e+01,   6.37000001e+06])
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I feel like an idiot now because I spent several hours trying to figure out why Python wasn't agreeing with my incorrect arrithmetic. I'll have to figure out why the Wolfram plot apparently isn't correct, but that is likely my mistake given my inexperience with Mathematica.